Create One Lake Data Access Roles using APIs (or some automation)
We have a requirement wherein we would like to automate the creation of One Lake Data Access Roles.
We went through the Fabric APIs documentation but weren't able to find anything helpful. Is there anyway via which we could achieve this?

Currently the OneLake Data access roles are in public preview and APIs are not yet available. We can only hope that APIs are available once this feature goes GA.
